# Looking for help to decrease runtime of my code in Python

Tags: python, list, performance, runtime

The overall goal of the code is the following:

The main list has x,y,z coordinates. I want to group rows together in which each x,y, and z coordinate is not more than +/-5 from eachother ("margin" variable). This grouping is denoted by the 4th column added to respective rows. All rows that do not match up (i.e. there is no other entry that is within +/-5 of each of the x,y,z coordinates) will be blank (at least for now). There are a few details in the code to prevent overwriting rows that are already grouped, and making sure the initial row isn't missed. By the way everything starts at counter = 1 because they real first row is the column headers.

The full .csv file has ~82500 rows. At the current rate of processing, this will take about 9 hours to run on my laptop (I used the "print(x)" line to determine this). I am a beginner with Python, so I am hoping there are some ways to make the code more efficient and decrease run time. Any tips are appreciated.

```
import csv

with open('just xyz.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    xyz_list = list(reader)


margin  = 5
ct = 0
rows = len(xyz_list)
columns = len(xyz_list[0])


for x in range(1, rows-1):
    print(x)
    for k in range(1, rows-1):
        if k+1 != x:
            
            if float(xyz_list[k+1][0]) >= (float(xyz_list[x][0]) + margin) or float(xyz_list[k+1][0]) <=(float(xyz_list[x][0]) - margin) or float(xyz_list[k+1][1]) >= (float(xyz_list[x][1]) + margin) or float(xyz_list[k+1][1]) <= (float(xyz_list[x][1]) - margin) or float(xyz_list[k+1][2]) >= (float(xyz_list[x][2]) + margin) or float(xyz_list[k+1][2]) <= (float(xyz_list[x][2]) - margin):
               
                pass
            elif int(len(xyz_list[k+1])) == 3:
        
               
                xyz_list[k+1].append(ct)
                
                if int(len(xyz_list[x])) == 3:
                    xyz_list[x].append(ct)
                
            else:
                pass
            
        else:
            pass
    ct = ct + 1

with open('new manual clusters.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(xyz_list)

print("Done")
```

I was just happy to get the code working at all on a smaller test file. Alternative methods are beyond my skill right now.

Comment: maybe you should use `pandas` instead of `csv` because `pandas` works with `csv` using `C/C++` code which can be much faster.

Comment: if you don't have code in `else:` then you can remove `else: pass`

Comment: you repeat similar calculations `float(xyz_list[x][0]) + margin` in every loop. Maybe you should first calculate all values and keep in next column - and later use these values in `if/else` without repeating calculations.

Comment: `len()` always gives integer value - so you don't have to use `int()`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample input (small) + expected output (in text form)?

Comment: Your keyword is "clustering", take a look at [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import time
from typing import List

# Check if the point q is withing the given margin of point p
def within_margin(p: List, q: List, margin: float=5.0):
    for i in range(3):
        if abs(p[i]-q[i]) <= margin:
            return True
    return False

# append the index of the row to keep track of it's position in the input list
def append_index(points: List[List]):
    for itr in range(len(points)):
        points[itr].append(itr)
    return points


def sort_list(points: List[List], index: int=0):
    return sorted(points, key=lambda x: x[index])

def group_points(point_list: List[List], margin:float=5.0):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # add None to 4th place (or the 3rd index)
    for p in point_list:
        p.append(None)
    
    # add row index to the list to keep track of the order
    point_list = append_index(point_list) 
    
    # Run pass based on each dimension
    for idx in range(3):
        # dim trace 0-x_trace, 1-y_trace, 2-z_trace
        # Sort the list based on dim-index
        point_list =sort_list(point_list.copy(), index=idx)
        
        for itr, p in enumerate(point_list):
            if itr%1000 ==0:
                print(idx, itr, time.time()-start_time)
            for itr2, q in enumerate(point_list[itr+1:]):
                # Check for dim-index here only
                # the list is sorted so exit the second loop if the point start going outside the margin
                if point_list[itr][-1] != point_list[itr2][-1] and abs(p[idx]-q[idx]) <= margin:
                    row_idx = min(point_list[itr][-1], point_list[itr2][-1])
                    if not point_list[itr][3]:
                        point_list[itr][3] = row_idx
                    if not point_list[itr2][3]:
                        point_list[itr2][3] = row_idx
                else:
                    break
    
    # revert back the list to its original order
    return sort_list(point_list, index=4)

def points_generator(num_sample: int=100, low_range:float=-1000.0, high_range:float=1000.0):
    samples = []
    for _ in range(num_sample):
        x = random.uniform(low_range, high_range)
        y = random.uniform(low_range, high_range)
        z = random.uniform(low_range, high_range)
        samples.append([x,y,z])
    return samples
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    xyz_list = points_generator(num_sample=82500)
    margin = 5
    start_time = time.time()
    xyz_list = group_points(xyz_list, margin)
        
    print("total time taken: ", time.time()- start_time)
```

In the absence of a provided sample file, I employed randomly generated 3D points. The algorithm utilized for this purpose involves a sequential sorting of each dimension, followed by a pairwise comparison of adjacent points within those dimensions. This process continues until a point is encountered that exceeds the specified margin within that particular dimension. I tested this on 100K points and it runs withing 1.5 minutes.

You need to slice each row at the end btw, which I left purposely.

The inclusion of sample data, along with corresponding sample output, would greatly facilitate a comprehensive understanding of the problem at hand. Moreover, it would enable the formulation of an enhanced and more tailored solution.